# Fungi by a passiflora plant - identification

Tags: identification, mushrooms

These little mushrooms appeared overnight in my garden (located in the Mediterranean region). I was wondering if anyone could help identify what they are. Closest species I got to was Mycena pelianthina but I'm almost certain it isn't it. Stalk is about 5mm wide, 3-5cm long, cap about 3.5cm wide. Gills barely apparent and are the same colour as the cap.

Thanks 
[image]

Comment: It seems that you know about mushroom much more that we know. BTW I'm more worried about the small yellow mushrooms.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the small yellow “mushrooms” look like slow-release fertilizer balls to me... but I admit it’s blurry.

Comment: Thank you for the answers/comments! The yellow balls are indeed a fertilizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right when you say you are wrong. This is nothing like *Pelianthina*.

This is clearly a close member of the [***Coprinus Genus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Coprinopsis_species). The hard part is those guys are dozens of sorts (and the genus got deeply reorganized recently in 2001)

But that one is pretty common I think, very similar to the one I had [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24071/is-this-mushroom-going-to-make-my-black-radish-taste-weird-or-be-poisonous?noredirect=1&lq=1) (France).

## Best guess

So I would say this is [*Coprinopsis Lagopus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinopsis_lagopus), because of the quickness of its growth and the way the cap developed:

[image]
By Tim Sage - 
This image is Image Number 122149 at Mushroom Observer, a source for mycological images.
This tag does not indicate the copyright status of the attached work. A normal copyright tag is still required. See [Commons:Licensing](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Licensing) for more information., [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=12106576)

## other possibility

It also could be [Coprinopsis Cinerea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinopsis_cinerea). Difficult to say.

Comment: Fantastic observation! You convinced me there!! It does look like _Coprinopsis Lagopus_. Much appreciated!